# How to expose Drools rules via REST

Tags: drools, redhat, redhat-brms

I'm trying out Redhat Drools and I was able to deploy Drools Workbench in WildFly environment. And I'm trying to find out how to expose rules as services, but couldn't find an article on how to do it. Is it a restriction on the Drools Workbench or is there another way where this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redhat BRMS just gives you a jar. To expose it as a rest api, you need to include it in a war and deploy that war on your server. Or as mentioned by Abhijit, you can use kie-server.war which serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of kie-server.war which was included in Drools 6 release. Through kie-server.war you can execute rules through REST API. Go through [document](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.CR1/drools-docs/html/ch22.html#d0e23962) for more details about kie-server